# Div to open after scrolling to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, hidden

I would like a hidden div to open once the reader has reached the bottom of the page. I found [one example that uses ASP and MySQL](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/). Is there a more simple way to do it with JavaScript and div toggle?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the post you're referring to has all the JS code necessary for reacting on the user scrolling to the bottom - only, instead of only showing something that was previously hidden, they make a call to the server to fetch more data to display, and that's when ASP and MySQL come into play.

You just need to do

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
       $('#idOfYourHiddenDiv').show();
    }
});
```

or something like that (assuming you have jQuery available)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "[slider up footer](http://return-true.com/2010/03/creating-a-slide-up-footer-using-jquery/)" can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Scroll to top control](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex3/scrolltop.htm) with some hack.
It has a parameter `startline`

> Integer. Number of pixels from top of doc scrollbar is scrolled before showing control

You can try to set this parameter to the [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) function, like in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623851/div-to-open-after-scrolling-to-bottom-of-page/6624013#6624013):

```
$(document).height() - $(window).height()
```

HTH.